# Apache Accessing static html without tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

During our maintenance windows we turn off our `tomcat`service and start `ApacheFacade` service which redirects request to a maintenance page `schedule.html` which is a static html. Below are the Rewrite rules in the ApacheFacade service

```
<Directory "C:/DC/SampleApp/ApacheFacade/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteRule  !^/ScheduledMaintenance/(.*)$ /ScheduledMaintenance/schedule.html  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(javascripts|stylesheets|images|help|yui)/(.*) /SampleApp/SD3/$1/$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule  ^/$  /ScheduledMaintenance/schedule.html  [R=301,L]
ProxyPass /SampleApp ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/SampleApp
ProxyPassReverse /SampleApp ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/SampleApp
```

When I turn off the tomcat and turn on the `ApacheFacade` service request going to `https://localhost/CPScheduledMaintenance/schedule.html` but its not loading the page and am seeing the below response

```
The requested URL /ScheduledMaintenance/schedule.html was not found on this server.
```

schedule.html is inside my web application directory at the root level 
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Created `ScheduledMaintenance` directory under `C:/DC/SampleApp/ApacheFacade/htdocs` and copied `schedule.html` to `ScheduledMaintenance` directory